# Exclude non-visible points from bake

Tags: camera, baking

I'm trying to bake the window coordinates onto an object's texture. It works fine, but the coordinates are baked on all pixels of the texture, even the ones which aren't visible from the camera. Is there an easy way of excluding non-visible points from a bake, or, alternatively, of directly baking visibility from a given camera?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is add a light constrained to follow the camera and bake shadows casted by that light. This way I can use that to mask out the parts of the texture which aren't visible from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Blender bakes based on the objects and their surface, it has nothing to do with the camera or the visibility. If you want to exclude parts from your bake, the only quick fix I see is to duplicate your object, scale all the UVs you don't want to one px and re-bake.

Comment: What I would like is to do is mask the bake result based on the visibility of each pixel from the camera (in other words, make the result black if the pixel is not visible from the camera from a given point of view). So I can't just manually exclude parts unfortunately. What I might try next is to pin a light to the camera so that the parts I don't care about are in shadow.

Comment: Oh, I thought by exclude from bake you meant don't use up space on the canvas. The light thing might work, that's a good idea.

Comment: It's a bit of a pain since I have to disable other light all the time, but it ended up working. Thanks for your help, btw

Comment: You're welcome. I think it would suit you to organize your lights in collections, that way you only have to click 2 buttons to switch between them.